# Monkey-patching class.__str__ using decorator not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-decorators, monkeypatching

I am trying to monkey-patch a class's `__str__` special method via the following decorator:

```py
def str_patcher(klass):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        def __str__(self):
            items = {key: value for key, value in self.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith("_")}
            return f"{type(self).__qualname__}({items})"

        klass.__str__ = __str__
        return klass

    return decorator
```

Then, I made a `MyClass` class decorated by `str_patcher`:

```py
@str_patcher
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

But when I printed out `MyClass(a=1, b=2, c=3)`, I expected to see `MyClass({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})` but I instead got `<class __main__.MyClass>`.

Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to patch `__str__`, and not `__repr__`?

Comment: Oh, I wanted the patch `__str__` first for testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You went one level to deep. The following is enough:

```
def str_patcher(klass):
    def __str__(self):
        items = {key: value for key, value in self.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith("_")}
        return f"{type(self).__qualname__}({items})"
    klass.__str__ = __str__
    return klass
```

Then:

```
@str_patcher
class Foo: pass

foo = Foo()
foo.bar = "baz"
print(foo)
# Foo({'bar': 'baz'})
```

Note that you used the pattern for a *parametrized* decorator. This would be useful if you wanted to add dynamic stuff to each decorated klass, but you would still need to change it up a little bit, e.g.:

```
def str_patcher(**kwargs):
    def decorator(klass):
        def __str__(self):
            items = {key: value for key, value in self.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith("_")}
            items.update(kwargs)
            return f"{type(self).__qualname__}({items})"
        klass.__str__ = __str__
        return klass
    return decorator

@str_patcher(funny="stuff")
class Foo: pass

foo = Foo()
foo.bar = "baz"
print(foo)
# Foo({'bar': 'baz', 'funny': 'stuff'})
```